# Autocompletion doesn't work for Swift subclass of Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, autocomplete, xcode6

I've some problem with Xcode's autocompletion.
I've a project written in swift that include some classes written in Objective-C, all works fine, but when I want to use a Objective-C class in swift Xcode doesn't help me, also if I subclass the original Objective-C class when I use that class Xcode doesn't autocomplete and show me "< < error type > >"

I've already cleaned derived data, restarted Xcode and restart my mac but nothing is changed.

I've also set to yes "Scan all source files for include" and of course ' ve added the correct Bridging-Header.

P.s. the code runs and works, it is only a autocompletion problem

Comment: Try change the simulator to different one. For example the autocompletion doesn't work for me when iPhone 5 simulator is selected but if I select iPhone 6 simulator or device all works fine.

Comment: mmmm with all simulators and devices i've the same problem :(